# javascript turn single line break to double line break

Tags: javascript

Hm... I'm trying to convert single line break into double line break, as in

> This is a sentence.
>   This is another sentence.

into

> This is a sentence.
>
> This is another sentence.

Apparently this doesn't work `ThisContent = ThisContent.replace(/(\n)/gm, "\n\n");` since it replace everything, including double line breaks.

What's the regex to do this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to leave double line breaks alone?

Comment: Yes, I want to leave double, triple and multiple line breaks alone. Just want to convert single to double, ie something like \n (not followed by any \n) to \n\n.

Comment: Correction, double linebreak becomes 4 line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

```
txt = txt.replace(/(^|[^\n])\n([^\n]|$)/g, "$1\n\n$2");
```

Comment: It seems to replace \n\n also. Those sentences that already have double linebreak becomes triple linebreaks.